# How do I split a string into sentences while maintaining all the spaces in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I tried the following regex:

```
sentences = sb.toString().split("(?<=[a-z])*\\.\\s*");
```

I am using a stringBuilder sb and converting it to string and then using a split function
The regex checks for 0 or more characters before '.' and 0 or more spaces after the '.'

However, it doesn't work for the following input

```
Hello World. Shipped to U.S on Friday.We are here .Good input
```

But I need to keep the space before We are here

Req Output

```
Hello World
 Shipped to U.S on Friday
 We are here
Good input
```

Comment: why cant u jst split on the `.`

Comment: Well, remove the `\\s*` part then?

Comment: @leoOrion I can only assume that the OP doesn't want to split on the dot in "15.05", for example.

Comment: 15.05?? uh?? what?

Comment: @leoOrion Um, what's so weird about 15.05 (as an example)?

Comment: @leoOrion yes, an output for U.S.A would give incorrect result

Comment: Can u then add the exact string on which u want to split?

Comment: @Learner Note that you also need to get rid of the `*` quantifier after the Lookbehind. Otherwise, it's virtually useless. I think what you need is something like `(?<=[a-z ])\\.`.

Comment: @leoOrion I don't have an exact string, it is more like covering all the edge cases. This regex is working fine overall except that it is not keeping the spaces before the start of a new sentence

Comment: @41686d6564 its not mentioned anywhere in the question. I considered it weird since I had no idea where it came from in this context

Comment: @leoOrion That's where "assume" and "for example" come into play :)

Comment: I really am not trying to pick a fight here. But I cant assume smthing about a question. There are so many things that can come into play.

Comment: @Learner what r the rules u r considering for a split in the line. U gave me an example of where not to split (U.S.A) But ur question has `.Good Input.` split into a new line.

Comment: @leoOrion something like U.S should not be split. If a space after a '.' then it should be kept along with the next sentence. End of the sentence may or may not have a '.'

Comment: Did you mean you want to split when there is `.` with space right side but split by `.` keeping space as it is ? Means how you take a decision logically for  `U.S` you don't want to split and for `Friday.We` you want to split ?

Comment: This is not possible. You cant code a rule that behaves in two different ways. If it should not split on `U.S`, then it should also not split on `Friday.We`.

Comment: @Learner - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 3):

use this regex: `([^\.]+)(\.|$)*?`
you can read about group matchers and see the full matches here : https://regex101.com/r/yV9GES/5

edit: updated the link for answer in the comment.

Comment: my bad! the closest i can come to match the OP's req is this regex: `/([^\.]+)(\.|$)*?/` It does break for `Shipped to U.S on Friday` though.

Answer (score 1):

Split your string using `\\.` i.e. on `.`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Hello World. We are here .Good input.".split("\\.")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello World,  We are here , Good input]
```

Comment: I think we need to add trim() for every generated statement.

Comment: @hiteshbedre - No. OP wants to keep the space. Please check his expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to use a RegEx?

You can simply use `indexOf` and `substring`

```
  public List<String> splitOnDot(String input) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int idx;
    while ((idx = input.indexOf('.')) != -1) {
      result.add(input.substring(0, idx));
      input = input.substring(idx + 1);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Successful test:

```
@Test
  public void test1() {
    assertThat(splitOnDot("Hello World. We are here .Good input.")).contains("Hello World", " We are here ", "Good input");
  }
```